# How to make invisible datatable when there is no data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

Is it possible to hide a table when it doesn't have any data(rows) inside?
I'm using the query datatables plugin.

I couldn't find any option in the [documentation](http://datatables.net/ref).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Despite good suggestions I think there still needs (another) answer.

1. Using dataTables a `<table>` will never be empty - or `:empty` - since dataTables enforces you to have a `<thead>` and a `<tbody>`
2. It is not enough to hide the `<table>`, you must hide the `*_wrappper` also - the `<div>` that contains the styled table, pagination, filter-box and so on.

You can take advantage of `fnInitComplete` :

```
$('#table').dataTable({
   //initialization params as usual
   fnInitComplete : function() {
      if ($(this).find('tbody tr').length<=1) {
         $(this).parent().hide();
      }
   } 
});
```

This will hide the dataTable and all its autogenerated content, **if** there is no rows holding data in `<tbody>`.

---

### Update

[See comments for clarification] Then you need a completely other approach. This works in Chrome and FireFox, cant tell for IE :

Forget about `fnInitComplete`, use the following code instead :

```js
var dataTable = $('#table').dataTable();

$("#table").on('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function() {
  if ($(this).find('tbody tr td').first().attr('colspan')) {
    $(this).parent().hide();
  } else {
    $(this).parent().show();
  }
});

//this shows the dataTable (simplified)
dataTable.fnAddData(
    ['a','b','c','d','e']
);

//this hides it (assuming there is only one row)
dataTable.fnDeleteRow(0);
```

Comment: This is a better answer but still there is a problem. I add or remove tr dynamically, so is it possible to make it work on every data manipulation? When I delete last row of table that must be hidden or when I add the first row table must be shown.

Comment: @ocanal, are you using fnAddData / fnDeleteRow?

Answer (score 4):

```
if($('#mytable tbody .dataTables_empty').length){
    $('#mytable_wrapper').hide()
}
```

see just because my id is `mytable` the wrapper is called `mytable_wrapper` so if your table id is`bla` it will be `bla_wrapper`

Answer (score 2):

I found that this works as well:

```
$('#table').dataTable({
    fnDrawCallback : function() {
        if ($(this).find('.dataTables_empty').length == 1) {
           $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Warning: If you search and no results it will hide the entire table.

Comment: This works well. You might want to add in `} else {
                        $(this).parent().show();
                    }` to bring the table back when clearing the search field.

Answer (score 2):

I did with draw event, for every time my datatable changes it checks if has data:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table.on('draw', function () {
    if (table.data().any()) {
        $(this).parent().show();
    } else {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With datatables, it will insert a row telling you that there is no data to display, so you need to check for that.  Directly after your call to populate the table, add this...

```
if ($(".dataTables_empty").length) {
    $(".dataTables_wrapper").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide table, when there is no any child tags in it (i mean when it is ) you can use pseudoclass `:empty` from css.

Something like that:

`table:empty {display: none}`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datatable1').dataTable({
        fnDrawCallback: function () {
            if ($(this).find('.dataTables_empty').length == 1) {
                $('th').hide();
                $('#datatable1_info').hide();
                $('#datatable1_paginate').hide();
                $('.dataTables_empty').css({ "border-top": "1px solid #111" });

            } else {
                $('th').show();
                $('#datatable1_info').show();
                $('#datatable1_paginate').show();
            }
        }, "oLanguage": { "sZeroRecords": "<p style='margin:0px !important'><a href='#' class='btn btn-success'>Add new</a></p>" }
    });
});
```

Comment: data table in if condition apply  1.) how can table header and footer remove with condition 2.) "no match record found" change add new button this table

Answer (score 0):

Yet another **CSS only** solution:

```
.dataTables_wrapper:has(.dataTables_empty) {
    display: none;
}
```

Please note that not every browser supports the **:has** selector yet:
https://caniuse.com/css-has