# Hide Datatable before fetching data from MySQL database

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am making a website where we can fetch data from MySQL and display in table. I am using datatable codes for responsive table with pagination and search option. When we open the page, the table remain empty and when we enter any word and hit enter, the data is fetched in table. I want to hide the table before fetching data as it is confusing visitor to input the searching term. Please help me to resolve this. Please see table circled with red mark I want to remove before search and show data in this table only after hitting search button.

[image: This is how it looks like before searching anything]

Comment: Why not initialize the table after the first search returns results?

Comment: Hi Anurag, thanks for your response. I am initializing table in header that is common for all other pages.

Comment: Then .hide() it before you return results and .show() once you have them.

Comment: Use css `style="display:none;"` then when you have results you change the style with JS to remove that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make invisible datatable when there is no data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296736/how-to-make-invisible-datatable-when-there-is-no-data)

Comment: @Sultan, I tried but not working in my case. Can you help implementing the codes? I am adding that code as <script> in head with change in #table with my table id.

Comment: Guys, I tried all above options, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Add below codes at JUST AFTER INITIALIZING TABLE

```
if ($(".dataTables_empty").length) {
$(".dataTables_wrapper").hide(); }
```

I did this to solve the problem

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable(); if ($(".dataTables_empty").length) { $(".dataTables_wrapper").hide();} } ); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi my friend try like this:

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="yourInputSearchValue" style="display:none">
<table class="display dataTable" id="exampleTable"  >
                                //Your columns here
                               </table>
                                 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#yourSubmit').on('click',function() {
console.log($('#yourInputSearchValue').val());
id = $.trim($('#yourInputSearchValue').val().replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
console.log(id);
$('#theDivthatContainsTheTable').hide();
exampleTable =$('#exampleTable').DataTable();
if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#exampleTable")) {
exampleTable.destroy();
$('#exampleTable tbody').remove();
}//this help when you search again
});
```

Hope it helps