# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined - ANGULAR 8

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring-boot, datatables

Please hope you can help me correct this "aDataSort" error in the datatables.

```
core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined
at _fnSortFlatten (jquery.dataTables.js:5928)
at _fnSortingClasses (jquery.dataTables.js:6266)
at loadedInit (jquery.dataTables.js:1208)
at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:1306)
at Function.each (jquery.js:381)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:203)
at jQuery.fn.init.DataTable [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.js:869)
at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.js:15210)
at angular-datatables.directive.js:51
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
```

It seems to me that the table in the html requires the table to have < thead> < tbody>.
But I am hiding it with an "if" when the table does not have any records.

```
<div *ngIf="programaciones?.length==0" class="alert alert-info">
        There is no record in the database!
    </div>

    <div class="table-responsive"  >
    <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
        <thead *ngIf="programaciones?.length>0">
            <tr >
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Consultorio</th>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Hora</th>
                <th>Num. Turno</th>
                <th>Editar</th>
                <th>Eliminar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
             <tr *ngFor="let programacion of programaciones" >
                <td>{{programacion.pro_codigo}}</td>
                <td>{{programacion.consultorio.con_nombre}}</td>
```

How can I correct this error, or is there some other way to hide the table when there are no records.

Comment: Do any of the approaches in this question help? [How to make invisible datatable when there is no data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296736/how-to-make-invisible-datatable-when-there-is-no-data)

Answer (score 0):

How about adding display: none/hidden instead of using ngIf

Something like this :

```
[ngStyle]="programaciones?.length>0 : {'display': 'block'} ? {'display': 'none'}
```

Comment: I have created a boolean variable vTable to test, but I can't hide the table.         
       >component.ts
 private vTable : boolean = false;

           >html
 <thead [ngStyle]="vTable ? {'display': 'block'} : {'display': 'hidden/none'}">

Comment: <thead [ngStyle]="{'vTable': true ? {'display': 'block'} : {'display': 'hidden/none'}}">

Comment: Oh, sorry. Issue is with your {'display': 'hidden/none'}. Display can take value of hidden, none or block so you should use just one of them for example {'display': 'none'}. Also check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Comment: I could already do it, I did it with 'none'. Thank you so much for help me.